# Oracle query for fetching data for a table where a column having null

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

`Select * from my_table where my_col1 is null.`

can we write above query in below format for oracle database if posible

`Select * from my_table where my_col1 = NULL`

any help?

Comment: Why would you do that if the first query is correct and second is not.

Comment: @yamny - just for my info that ,whether we have any way to do this or not.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `null` means literally *nothing*. `null` is not a value, you cannot compare some *value* with *nothing*. If you try to do that, the evaluation will be neither `true` or `false`, but `unknown`. You can only check if there is value or not with `is (not) null` statement. For more reference [look at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm#g194888).